# What is the Redshift parameter for Enhanced Vpc Routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

Anybody has any idea what is the parameter in Cloudformation to enable the Enhanced Vpc Routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is no support official parameter to support this but it is [on the roadmap](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/51).

If you want to enable this in CloudFormation you would need to [create a custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that uses the SDK within a Lambda and modifies the cluster to use enhanced VPC routing once the cluster has been launched.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html#cfn-redshift-cluster-enhancedvpcrouting) link.

The option that specifies whether to create the cluster with enhanced VPC routing enabled is 'EnhancedVpcRouting'.
The cluster must be created within VPC to support this.